# Is there an event to watch for when a user follows a person/document/site/tag?

Tags: development, social, following

We are doing R&D on integrating the updates post in Confluence with the SharePoint newsfeed. One thing I need to do is create a "listener" that can update a central content store when a user follows an object (person/site/etc.). Right now, I can find a couple ways to enumerate what objects a user is following (or who is following a user), but nothing on how to capture the event of following (to add an entry to the central store) or retrieve a list of follows since the last request (similar to using SocialFeedOptions.NewerThan to get posts from the previous collection instance).

Am I missing something or would we have to do a timer job that steps through every person's following list, compare it to the central store, and then make updates as needed? That seems pretty inefficient, but I can't find anything else.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such event, and likes/follows are not tracked via the change log. Furthermore, the Newsfeed is being replaced by Yammer, which is completely cloud based. Polling on an interval is likely your best approach.

Comment: That's what I thought, but thanks for confirming it. I can stop digging through the object model looking for something that doesn't exist now.